# Proper QuerySet query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models in Django: one of them is a bunch of entries, and another model is a link table - it basically maps one entry to another, so it has a entry_a_id and an entry_b_id field... how do I write a QuerySet query to properly select the first entry's related fields then the second one?

=== EDIT ===

Here's an example:

```
class Nodes(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Links(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    node_a_id = models.ForeignKey('Nodes')
    node_b_id = models.ForeignKey('Nodes')
```

So, with that said (or typed), I would like to be able to figure out how to have a final result of `node_a_id`, `name`, `description`, `node_b_id`, `name`, `description` according to the `Links` model. Let me know if you want me to clarify further.

Comment: your question is not clear. can you include simple definitions of your models and the query results you want?

Answer (score 0):

I might have misunderstood but here I go. Having a `Link` object:

```
>>> link = Links.objects.all()[0]
```

You automagically have access to the fields of your foreign relations (`node_a_id` and `node_b_id`). With that, you can do the following:

```
>>> link = Links.objects.all()[0]
>>> link.node_a_id.id
1
>>> link.node_a_id.name
'Name for node A'
>>> link.node_a_id.description
'Description for node B'
>>> link.node_b_id.id
2
>>> link.node_b_id.name
'Name for node B'
>>> link.node_b_id.description
'Description for node B'
```

As a side note, there is no point in using `id` as your auto-incrementing primary key field since you get that for free: [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#autofield) and [Automatic primary key fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#automatic-primary-key-fields)